# TypeScript: "TypedArray" interface for Typed Arrays

Tags: typescript, typed-arrays

How do I tell TypeScript that given parameter contains one of the [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)?

It is not uncommon to have the ability to choose the type of Typed Array that best suits your needs (for instance the [Flatbush](https://github.com/mourner/flatbush) library does this).

I want to check if what is passed into the constructor indeed identifies one of the Typed Arrays. But in my lib.es6.d.ts none of the Typed Arrays inherit from a common interface.

related question: What is the "ArrayLike" interface used for?

Comment: This [has been suggested](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402) before.

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in alias, but you can create one yourself based on the types from `lib.es2017.typedarrays.d.ts`.

```
type TypedArray =
  | Int8Array
  | Uint8Array
  | Uint8ClampedArray
  | Int16Array
  | Uint16Array
  | Int32Array
  | Uint32Array
  | Float32Array
  | Float64Array
  | BigInt64Array
  | BigUint64Array;
```

To answer your second question: not every collection used in the browser is implemented with proper arrays. Some data structures like `NodeListOf` or `AggregateError` have different methods on them, but share one similarity — they can be indexed by numbers. You can think of `ArrayLike` as an abstract type used to describe such an object.

**Edit**: Added `BigInt64Array | BigUint64Array` as per suggestion from @Codesmith

Comment: Be sure to also include `BigInt64Array` and `BigUint64Array` which are also typed arrays as of ES2020.

Answer (score 3):

typescript doesn't have a `TypedArray` interface but like the suggestion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15402#issuecomment-299702084), you can use [ArrayBufferView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) which is a supertype of all typed arrays.

Comment: ArrayBufferView isn't a supertype (union type) of all typed arrays, for example, it doesn't have a `length` property. Due to this lack of equivalence, one can't perform 
`let a: ArrayBufferView, acc = 0; for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) acc += a[i];`
because TS will complain that `ArrayBufferView` has no `length` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not happy using `ArrayBufferView`, as per [@tobenna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926165/5405968), the only other option would be to create your own `TypedArray` interface.

```
type TypedArray =
  | Int8Array
  | Uint8Array
  | Uint8ClampedArray
  | Int16Array
  | Uint16Array
  | Int32Array
  | Uint32Array
  | Float32Array
  | Float64Array;
```

Note: unlike the `ArrayBufferView` method, this excludes `DataView` objects.

Finally, the `ArrayLike` interface is used for everything that can be indexed by a number and has a length. This includes things like the DOM `NodeList`, which doesn't contain the majority of methods on the `Array` prototype.